# DevExpress Microsoft Visual C#

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

Anybody is familiar with DevExpress in Microsoft Visual C#?

My boss gave me the code to study and this code has the version of DevExpress 8.3. 
And I would like to open this code in my laptop which has already a version of DevExpress 9.1
Would that be a problem finding the files?
Thanks a lot!

Regards
tintincute

Comment: Did you even try to build the project? Was it a problem finding the files?

Comment: yes it has problem finding the files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DevExpress has a convertion tool located under start -> all programs -> developper .NET vx.x -> tools -> ProjectConvertor

That should do the trick

Comment: Thanks Tarscher, should I just simply click on the ProjectConverter? can I still do it although I don't have internet? My other Pc is not connected to the internet...

Comment: no internet connection required. It's the project file you need to open and convert.

Comment: Do I just simply click this ProjectConverter?

Comment: click it, select the project and click upgrade

Comment: I was asked about the Project Path. Shall I select the folder where I saved my project?This means,my code folder name as Assistant shall I just select this one?

Comment: last night I added some reference to it. Will it be a problem? Because now I'm seeing under my References - DevExpress.Data v8.3 and DevExpress.Data v9.1. can i simply delete the new references I added yesterday? Or can I just leave it and then upgrade?

Comment: ok I think I just did it. Now I'm seeing a message conversion complete. But I didn't get any thing what to do, can I just simply close this?

Comment: hey Tarscher thank you so much for your help. Now the code is working in my PC:-) I hope I can understand the code in the program. It's fun working like this;-) have a good day ahead;-)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to just look at the code, it should be fine.

For compiling, you have to convert the project to use DevExpress 9.1. You can either use the DevExpress tool to upgrade or manually remove and add the references to use 9.1.

Comment: I also would like to compile the code. How will I convert the project to use DevExpress 9.1?

Comment: Do you have a tool called XTraConvertor or ProjectConvertor under your DevExpress 9.1 Programs Menu?

Comment: this link might be helpful http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/winforms/archive/2006/04/10/upgrading-my-project-to-a-new-version-of-xtra-controls-it-s-easy.aspx

Comment: hey thanks Gulzar. Yes I have the ProjectConverter under DeveloperExpress vxxx - Components - Tools.
Shall I simply click this one? At the moment my other PC don't have an internet connection. Can I still do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the project converter from devexpress 9.1 and convert the old version to this new one.
Probably you will have some issues of some method depreciated but not that much.